# Need Help on JUnit Test

Tags: java

I was told that i should make a JUnit Test to check if all the codes are working. I dont know anything about JUnit that Is why im asking you guys. Anyway, here is my code:

```
package cst8284.shape;

public abstract class BasicShape {

    private double width;

    public double getWidth(){return width;}
    public void setWidth(double width){this.width = width;}

    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ("BasicShape Overrides " + super.toString());
    }

    public abstract double getArea();
    public abstract double getPerimeter();

}
```

Here is where i should make testing,

```
package cst8284.shape;

public class TestBasicShape {

    public static void main(String[] args){

        Circle circle = new Circle(2.0);
        System.out.println(circle.toString());
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the circle is " + circle.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The area of the circle is: " + circle.getArea() + "\n");

        Square square = new Square(2.0);
        System.out.println(square.toString());
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the square is " + square.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The area of the square is: " + square.getArea() + "\n");

        Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(2.0,3);
        System.out.println(rect1.toString());
        System.out.println("The perimeter of the rectangle is " + rect1.getPerimeter());
        System.out.println("The area of the rectangle is: " + rect1.getArea() +"\n");

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(rect1);
        Rectangle rect3 = new Rectangle(2.0, 1.0);

        System.out.println("The square and the circle are " + (square.equals(circle)?"":"not ") + "equal");
        System.out.println("The rectangle and the square are " + (rect1.equals(square)?"":"not ") + "equal");
        System.out.println("Rectangles 1 and 2 are " + (rect2.equals(rect1)?"":"not ") + "equal");
        System.out.println("Rectangles 2 and 3 are " + (rect2.equals(rect3)?"":"not ") + "equal");

    }


}

package cst8284.shape;

public class Circle extends BasicShape {

    public Circle(){

    }
    public Circle(double width){
        setWidth(width);
    }
    public Circle(Circle circle) {
        setWidth(circle.getWidth());
    }

    //Getters
    public double getArea() {
        return Math.PI * (getWidth()/2) * (getWidth()/2);
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2*Math.PI*getWidth()/2;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ("Circle Overrides " + super.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (!(obj instanceof Circle)) {
            return false;
        }
        Circle c = (Circle)obj;
        return (this.getWidth() == c.getWidth());
        }
}

package cst8284.shape;

public class Square extends BasicShape{

    public Square() {

    }

    public Square(double width) {
        setWidth(width);
    }
    public Square(Square square) {
        setWidth(square.getWidth());
    }

    //Getters

    public double getArea() {
        return getWidth()*2;
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 4*getWidth();
    }



    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ("Square Overrides " + super.toString());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (!(obj instanceof Square)) {
            return false;
        }
        Square s = (Square)obj;
        return (this.getWidth() == s.getWidth());
        }
}

package cst8284.shape;

public class Rectangle extends Square{

    private double height;

    public Rectangle() {

    }
    public Rectangle(double width, double height) {
        setWidth(width);
        setHeight(height);
    }
    public Rectangle(Rectangle rectangle) {
        setWidth(rectangle.getWidth());
        setHeight(rectangle.getHeight());
    }


    public double getHeight(){
        return height;
    }
    public void setHeight(double height){
        this.height=height;
    }


    public double getArea() {
        return getWidth()*getHeight();
    }
    public double getPerimeter() {
        return 2*(getHeight()+getWidth());
    }


    @Override
    public String toString(){
        return ("Rectangle Overrides " + super.toString());
    }
    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj){
        if (!(obj instanceof Rectangle)) {
            return false;
        }

        Rectangle r = (Rectangle)obj;
        return (this.getWidth() == r.getWidth() && this.getHeight() == r.getHeight());
    }
}
```

In this program, i am trying to calculate the area and perimeter of Circle and Square(subclasses of BasicShape) and Rectangle(subclass of Square) and also trying to compare whether each shape are equal(in shape or in size)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: So you don't know how to use JUnit? To get you started: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JUnit/article.html

Comment: As a side note, your class hierarchy is flawed.  A rectangle *is not* a square, but rather a square is a special kind of rectangle.  If I create a function that expects a square, and you pass in an object that isn’t square, my function could break.  Where as if I create a function that takes a rectangle, and you pass in a square object, my function should work without issue, because a square *is a* rectangle, just with some extra constraints.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the easiest way to approach testing is to make a test class for each of the classes whose behaviour you would like to test in your system, and place these test classes in a separate package.
Then, say you want to test the methods in the rectangle class.

```
//imports
public void testRectangle(){
Rectangle rectange;

@Before
public void setup(){
rectangle = new Rectangle();
}

//Say you want to test whether the setHeight method works as it should
@Test
public void testSetHeight(){
rectangle.setHeight(10.0);
assertEquals(10.0, rectangle.getHeight());
}

//The rest of the methods you would like to test
```

A few things to note :
Methods in the test class never takes in any parameters.
@Before means the method is going to run before each of the test methods. This allows you to setup anything you will need for the tests to run. You must have @Test before each test method. The example I have provided above is very simple and by no means exhaustive, so you should look up the JUnit documentation and learn more.